# Customize URL to a failed build in MailNotifier

Tags: buildbot

When my buildbot fails, it is configured to send an email.

Current configuration is:

```
mailNotify = MailNotifier(fromaddr="****@****.com",
sendToInterestedUsers=True,
extraRecipients=['*****@*****.com', '****@****.com'],
relayhost="mail.****.com",
smtpPort=587,
addLogs = True,
addPatch = True,
useTls=True,
smtpUser="****@****.com",
smtpPassword="****"
mode="failing")
```

I have a buildmaster setup in my local network, at 192.168.1.11. Because of that, when an email comes, it contains the following information:

```
Full details are available at:
 http://192.168.1.11:8020/builders/BuilderName/builds/136

Buildbot URL: http://192.168.1.11:8020/
```

Apart from that, I have a publicly accessible server, by which I can access buildbot, i.e. `https://mydomain.com/buildbot/`

What I want to get is

```
Full details are available at:
https://mydomain.com/buildbot/builders/BuilderName/builds/136

Buildbot URL: https://mydomain.com/buildbot/
```

I'd love NOT to rewrite a whole message formatter, but I couldn't find a way to do that. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK the best way is to write your own `messageFormatter()`. It is not much of a pain. I have done it for my buildbot and it works like a charm.

If you look into the sources `buildbot\status\mail.py` there is function called `defaultMesage(...)`. Just override this in your buildbot's configuration and pass it to the `MailNotifier` constructor ! Most likely you have to change just the line:108

```
def myMessageFormatter(mode, name, build, results, master_status)
    # Copy everything from buildbot\status\mail.py:defaultMessage()

    # Change this to point to https://mydomain.com/buildbot/
    if master_status.getURLForThing(build):
        text += "Full details are available at:\n %s\n" % master_status.getURLForThing(build)
    text += "\n"
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. It needed a little tinkering for a python newbie, but I finally achieved my goal :)